# Are noscript tags supposed to be defined for every script tag or only once?

Tags: html, noscript

I was reading up on some basic html in which I read that you can use `<noscript>` after a `<script>` to define if the client doesn't support running the script. Should this be redefined for every script tag or does one define every case?

So should I do this:

```
<script>
</script>
<script>
</script>
<noscript></noscript>
```

or:

```
<script>
</script>
<noscript></noscript>
<script>
</script>
<noscript></noscript>
<script>
</script>
<noscript></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its only purpose is to display content in browsers that can't run the script. It's up to you to decide whether and where you want to display fallback content. From [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript):

> The <noscript> HTML element defines a section of HTML to be inserted if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting is currently turned off in the browser.

Comment: But should it be defined for every script tag or just once?

Comment: Do you want to display HTML content in more than one place in browsers without javascript enabled? It's completely unrelated to your <script> tags.

Comment: Yes, if I have multiple scripts in one file does the noscript work for all of them?

Comment: If the browser can't run scripts it will display the content in however many <noscript> tags you include, wherever you include them, regardless of whether there are any scripts in your page at all.

Comment: Or can I customize the noscript for each individual script

Comment: Think of it this way: It's just a `div` that will be hidden in browsers that can run javascript.

Comment: alright that makes sense, I didn't know if it was customizable for each script although I'm realizing the use for that is probably unlikely